# Android publish database for uploading and downloading file

Tags: android, database, sqlite, google-play, google-cloud-datastore

This application will be my first application that I am planning publish. I wrote application and it works on emulator with database. Users file(xls,doc,img) input will convert to byte and uploaded as BLOB. I used SQLITE for database. The problem I have is how would I publish this application with database. As I search I saw something called cloud-based database. Do I have to use it or are there any easy way to do it? We are going to keep at most 1 GB data.

The application will work on Android and in future it will be on IOS.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are people supposed to upload their files into this local database that exists on their own phone only? What part needs to be published in this case? Blob has a 1 MB limit or so btw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300407/access-large-blob-in-android-sqlite-without-cursor

Comment: @zapl yes people will upload their own files to database. I was not aware from 1 MB limit of BLOB.

Comment: Please share more details on your use case: Users should be able to see other users shared data? What is the expected maximum file size? Is it really necessary to permanently store users file locally? You added a Google Datastore tag. Datastore is not a good solution to store files. Primarily, because of the entity size limit (1mb). Secondary, because its speed advantage will be lost if accessed via JSON API from a mobile device. It can be used to store a reference to a file uploaded to Google Cloud Storage. GCS will be much cheaper too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this good component to ship your app with a preinstalled database https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: But I already created database. What I need to know is if I publish this application, will database be published also? if not how can I managed to make user see same data. @Alex

Comment: You publish an apk, nothing else. If you want your apk to contain an already non-empty database use this component as described.

Comment: -1, link only answer. Should be a comment or provide a decent amount of extra information from the link. IMO. The library also isn't totally necessary. [this q/a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database) covers how to do it yourself, and I think it's worth mentioning.